# MediaControllerCompat returning wrong state

Tags: android-mediaplayer, media, playback, android-mediasession

In my app, I am instantiating a `MediaControllerCompat` with a valid `Token` and here is the issue that I am encountering:
The value that I am getting from `mController.getPlaybackState().getPosition()` is the length of my audio instead of its position, and last time I update the state on the `MediaSession` object I did set it with the correct playback position.

It is probably something in my code, but just wondering if there is anything in the instantiation process of `MediaControllerCompat` that can make this happen.

Comment: Did you found solution to your problem? i have the same problem, the new instantiated MediaControllerCompat with a valid Token returns wrong PlaybackState position and wrong last updated time.